# If $a$, $b$ are rotations of $S^2$ through the same angle, show that they are conjugate in $SO(3)$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Basically everything to do with the question is in the title! I'm just not really sure where to begin with this question, as I don't want to get bogged down in complicated matrix multiplication. I'm sure there must be a more geometric argument, for example because the determinant is equal to 0, $S^2$ cannot enlarge at all, but I'm not sure what other knowledge to use?

Comment: The determinant of what is zero?

Comment: Euler's rotation theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed $\mathbf{S}^2$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$. For each rotation has a unique vector line on which it acts as the identity, and acts as a plane rotation on the orthogonal plane to this vector line, take both such vector lines for your two rotations of same angle, and take both associated orthogonal planes. As both rotations have same angle, your two rotations have the same matrix in two (different, associated to the decompostion "fixed line$\oplus$orthogonal plane") orthonormal basis of $\mathbf{R}^3$. Then simply take the change of basis matrix for this couple of basis, and it will give you the matrix realizing conjugation between you two rotations, and ensure that this matrix is in $SO(3,\mathbf{R})$, which is always possible.

Answer (score 1):

The two axes of rotation lie in a plane.  Let $C$ be the rotation that takes $A$'s axis to $B$'s axis.  Then $C^{-1}BC$ fixes $A$'s axis, and rotates the rest of space through the correct angle relative to the axis.

Comment: If you are not careful with which way you take $A$'s axis to $B$'s axis you may get $C^{-1}BC=A^{-1}$ instead.

Comment: Oh yes, I hadn't thought of that.  But to define a rotation as an axis and an angle, there is a symmetry $(\vec{v},\theta)\equiv(-\vec{v},-\theta)$, so if I know the sign of $\theta$, I guess I can know the direction the axis is pointing.